# Java, Colours of a buffered image are completely different to the original image

Tags: java, image, graphics, bufferedimage

I am trying to add some texture to my game. I am running into some problems getting the image to display properly.

This is what the texture should look like, just a boring black square:

[image: boring black square]

And this is what I get. A little bit of black with blue lines.

[image]

This is the code I used to import the image. The BufferedImage is set to `Type_INT_RGB`:

```
package com.mime.minefront.graphics;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Texture {

    public static Render floor = loadBitmap("/textures/floorb.png");

    public static Render loadBitmap(String fileName) {
        try {
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(Texture.class.getResource(fileName));
            int width = image.getWidth();
            int height = image.getHeight();
            Render result = new Render(width, height);
            image.getRGB(0, 0, width, height, result.pixels, 0, width);
            return result;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("CRASH!");
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

}
```

Any help or advice would be great. I have tried to search for the answer but with no luck.

This is my `Render` class.

```
package com.mime.minefront.graphics;

public class Render {

public final int width;
public final int height;
public final int[] pixels;

public Render(int width, int height) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    pixels = new int[width * height];
}

public void draw(Render render, int xOffset, int yOffset) {
    for (int y = 0; y < render.height; y++) {
        int yPix = y + yOffset;

        if (yPix < 0 || yPix >= height) {
            continue;
        }
        for (int x = 0; x < render.width; x++) {
            int xPix = x + xOffset;
            if (xPix < 0 || xPix >= width) {
                continue;
            }

            int aplha = render.pixels[x + y * render.width];
            if (aplha > 0) {
                pixels[xPix + yPix * width] = aplha;
            }
        }

    }
 }

}
```

and this is my `Render3D` class

```
package com.mime.minefront.graphics;

import com.mime.minefront.Game;
import com.mimi.minefront.input.Controller;
import com.mimi.minefront.input.InputHandler;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.util.Random;

public class Render3D extends Render {

public double[] zBuffer;
private double renderDistance = 5000;
private double forward, right, up, cosine, sine;

public Render3D(int width, int height) {
    super(width, height);
    zBuffer = new double[width * height];
}

public void floor(Game game) {

    double floorPosition = 8;
    double cellingPosition = 8;
    forward = game.controls.z;
    right = game.controls.x;
    up = game.controls.y;
    double walking = Math.sin(game.time / 6.0) * 0.5;
    if (Controller.crouchWalk) {
        walking = Math.sin(game.time / 6.0) * 0.25;
    }
    if (Controller.runWalk) {
        walking = Math.sin(game.time / 6.0) * 0.8;
    }

    double rotation = 0;//Math.sin(game.time / 20) * 0.5; //game.controls.rotation;
    cosine = Math.cos(rotation);
    sine = Math.sin(rotation);

    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        double celling = (y - height / 2.0) / height;

        double z = (floorPosition + up) / celling;
        if (Controller.walk) {
            z = (floorPosition + up + walking) / celling;
        }

        if (celling < 0) {
            z = (cellingPosition - up) / -celling;
            if (Controller.walk) {
                z = (cellingPosition - up - walking) / -celling;
            }
        }

        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            double depth = (x - width / 2.0) / height;
            depth *= z;
            double xx = depth * cosine + z * sine;
            double yy = z * cosine - depth * sine;
            int xPix = (int) (xx + right);
            int yPix = (int) (yy + forward);
            zBuffer[x + y * width] = z;
            pixels[x + y * width] = //((xPix & 15) * 16 | ((yPix % 15) * 16) << 8);
                    Texture.floor.pixels[xPix & 7] + (yPix & 7) * 8;

            if (z > 500) {
                pixels[x + y * width] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}

public void renderWall(double xLeft, double xRight, double zDistance, double yHeight) {
    double xcLeft = ((xLeft) - right) * 2;
    double zcLeft = ((zDistance) - forward) * 2;

    double rotLeftSideX = xcLeft * cosine - zcLeft * sine;
    double yCornerTL = ((-yHeight) - up) * 2;
    double yCornerBL = ((+0.5 - yHeight) - up) * 2;
    double rotLeftSideZ = zcLeft * cosine + xcLeft * sine;

    double xcRight = ((xRight) - right) * 2;
    double zcRight = ((zDistance) - forward) * 2;

    double rotRightSideX = xcRight * cosine - zcLeft * sine;
    double yCornerTR = ((-yHeight) - up) * 2;
    double yCornerBR = ((+0.5 - yHeight) - up) * 2;
    double rotRightSideZ = zcRight * cosine + xcRight * sine;

    double xPixelLeft = (rotLeftSideX / rotLeftSideZ * height + width / 2);
    double xPixelRight = (rotRightSideX / rotRightSideZ * height + width / 2);

    if (xPixelLeft >= xPixelRight) {
        return;
    }

    int xPixelLeftInt = (int) (xPixelLeft);
    int xPixelRightInt = (int) (xPixelRight);

    if (xPixelLeftInt < 0) {
        xPixelLeftInt = 0;
    }
    if (xPixelRightInt > width) {
        xPixelRightInt = width;
    }

    double yPixelLeftTop = (yCornerTL / rotLeftSideZ * height + height / 2);
    double yPixelLeftBottom = (yCornerBL / rotLeftSideZ * height + height / 2);
    double yPixelRightTop = (yCornerTR / rotRightSideZ * height + height / 2);
    double yPixelRightBottom = (yCornerBR / rotRightSideZ * height + height / 2);

    double tex1 = 1 / rotLeftSideZ;
    double tex2 = 1 / rotRightSideZ;
    double tex3 = 0 / rotLeftSideZ;
    double tex4 = 8 / rotRightSideZ - tex3;

    for (int x = xPixelLeftInt; x < xPixelRightInt; x++) {

        double pixelRotation = (x - xPixelLeft) / (xPixelRight - xPixelLeft);

        double xTexture= (int) ((tex3+tex4*pixelRotation)/tex1+(tex2-tex1)*pixelRotation);

        double yPixelTop = yPixelLeftTop + (yPixelRightTop - yPixelLeftTop) * pixelRotation;
        double yPixelBottom = yPixelLeftBottom + (yPixelRightBottom - yPixelLeftBottom) * pixelRotation;

        int yPixelTopInt = (int) (yPixelTop);
        int yPixelBottomInt = (int) (yPixelBottom);

        if (yPixelTopInt < 0) {
            yPixelTopInt = 0;
        }
        if (yPixelBottomInt > height) {
            yPixelBottomInt = height;
        }

        for (int y = yPixelTopInt; y < yPixelBottomInt; y++) {
            pixels[x + y * width] = (int) xTexture*100;
            zBuffer[x + y * width] = 0;
        }
    }
}

public void renderDistanceLimiter() {
    for (int i = 0; i < width * height; i++) {
        int colour = pixels[i];
        int brightness = (int) (renderDistance / (zBuffer[i]));

        if (brightness < 0) {
            brightness = 0;
        }

        if (brightness > 255) {
            brightness = 255;
        }

        int r = (colour >> 16) & 0xff;
        int g = (colour >> 8) & 0xff;
        int b = (colour) & 0xff;

        r = r * brightness / 255;
        g = g * brightness / 255;
        b = b * brightness / 255;

        pixels[i] = r << 16 | g << 8 | b;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Perhaps your issue lies in the `Render` class. Could you post the code you used to draw the `Render`?

Comment: I have a `Render` class and a `Render3D`. I will add the code to the question

Comment: what is the purpose of `pixels[x + y * width] = Texture.floor.pixels[xPix & 7] + (yPix & 7) * 8;` ?

Comment: it is adding the floor texture to the pixels array

Comment: `Texture.floor.pixels[xPix & 7] + (yPix & 7) * 8;` looks sketchy: you  are getting the color and then adding to the color  an int based on the y coords. it probably should be `Texture.floor.pixels[xPix & 7 + (yPix & 7) * 8]`

Comment: That fixed that problem thank you :) But i now have a new one. Everything to my right is not textured properly ![New Problem] (http://i1368.photobucket.com/albums/ag187/dannyb1071/Untitled_zps2b26e56a.png)

Comment: I cannot see the issue in the code you have posted. Would reccommend you upload all the code that was used to render the last image you posted to some file sharing service/repository and link. At this point i am not certain that SO is the right place for this.

Comment: Ok i have uploaded the whole zip file containing everything (http://www.sendspace.com/file/w4ptmf)

Comment: I have found out what the problem was. i put this `[xPix & 7 + (yPix & 7) * 8];` instead of `[(xPix & 7) + (yPix & 7) * 8);`

Answer (score 0):

From [getRGB()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getRGB%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%5b%5d,%20int,%20int%29) :

> Returns an array of integer pixels in the default RGB color model
>   (TYPE_INT_ARGB) and default sRGB color space, from a portion of the
>   image data. Color conversion takes place if the default model does not
>   match the image ColorModel

See if using `TYPE_INT_ARGB` instead of `TYPE_INT_RGB` works.

Comment: Unfortunatly all that happened by changing to `TYPE_INT_ARGB` was the whole screen goes gray.